# SQL DataAdapter Inserting Single row across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am interested in using the SQLDataAdapter with the DataTable and associated Insert/Update/Delete Command operations that I can attach to the Adapter object. My question is this. Does each row in the datatable used necessarily need to correspond to any one physical table ? What I would like to be able to do is allow a single row to represent columns that span multiple tables and then craft each of the insert/update commands to handle their operations across these tables. That would mean that what I assign to the command might actually be a more complex sql statement even wrapped in BEGIN/END so that I can insert into the first "anchor" table then use that primary key and for the foreign key column of the subsequent column.

So far all the examples I see relate to each data table representing a single table. I realize that I could perhaps use a dataset but then how would I attach a command relative to each data table within the set. Furthermore how then could I relate the rows from table to the rows of the dhild table.?

Anyone try this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a View with an instead of insert trigger. Within the trigger you can split the columns as you like and do multiple inserts to different tables.